# Get custom attribute's value in Index (cms, home page)

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I have custom attribute called `slider_link` and trying to display it's value in home/index/cms page. I use the following code:

```
<?php echo $_product->getData("slider_link"); ?>
```

After adding this, my index page dose not load.

However, I had used above code on my `view.phtml` and `list.phtml` with no errors. everything is working fine.

Any idea how can I get the attribute value of my custom attribute called `slider_link` on my home page?

***UPDATED***

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <?php 
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $products->joinField(
    'qty', 
    'cataloginventory/stock_item', 
    'qty', 
    'product_id=entity_id', 
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 
    'left' 
    );
    $products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'price', 'special_price' , 'RegularPrice' )); //ovdje idu atributi
    $products->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id=entity_id', null, 'left' );
    $products->getSelect()->limit(5);
    $products->getSelect()->order('RAND()'); // random sortiranje
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array(21))); // ubacujem kategorije id
    $this->_reviewsHelperBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper'); // pozivanje review helper, da bi se prikazao review summary
    foreach ($products as $product)  : 
    ?> 
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText("slider_link"); ?>"><img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(780, 395)?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName()?>"></a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What code are your using on your homepage (I need to know the block type and template)?

Comment: i just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling this

```
<?php echo $_product->getData("slider_link"); ?>
```

but the variable `$_product` does not exist.
you loop looks like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product)  :
```

So you should use `echo $product->getData("slider_link")` with no underscore  for the product variable.

Also, you should add the attribute `slider_link` to the collection.
This

```
$products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'price', 'special_price' , 'RegularPrice' )); //ovdje idu atributi
```

should be

```
$products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'price', 'special_price' , 'RegularPrice', 'slider_link' )); //ovdje idu atributi
```

Comment: tnx bro for clearing this up for me

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$_product->getAttributeText("slider_link")` to get the attribute value, but the product collection is loaded with $product so use this

```
$product->getAttributeText("slider_link");
```

```
foreach ($products as $product)  : 
    ?> 
        <li>
             <a href="<?php echo $product->getAttributeText("slider_link"); ?>"><img class="thumbnail" src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(780, 395)?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName()?>">
              </a>
         </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```