# Custom Attribute listing

Tags: cms, product-list, cms-block, cms-pages

Hello I have created one custom attribute "Brand" with select box and add lots of brand for product. Now I want to display brand value with alphabets order in cms page.

Comment: Is this what you need? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75426/get-custom-attributes-value-in-index-cms-home-page